# How do I make git-svn use a particular svn branch as the remote repository?

Tags: git, svn, repository, branch, git-svn

A word of warning: I'm a n00b to `git` in general. My team uses feature branches in `svn`, and I'd like to use `git-svn` to track my work on a particular feature branch. I've been (roughly) following [Andy Delcambre's post](http://andy.delcambre.com/2008/03/04/git-svn-workflow.html) to set up my local `git` repo, but those instructions seem to have led `git` to pick the `svn` branch that had changed most recently as the remote repository; the problem is that's not the branch I care about. How do I control which branch `git-svn` uses? Or am I approaching this completely wrong?

UPDATE: I did use the `-T`, `-b`, and `-t` options (in my case because the `svn` repo has multiple projects, but I want the `git` repo to contain only the project I'm working on).

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Muchas gracias to Bart's Blog for this handy [reference for svn branches in git](http://www.jukie.net/~bart/blog/svn-branches-in-git). Apparently all I needed was to specify a remote branch when creating the `git` branch, e.g.,

```
git checkout -b git-topic-branch-foo foo
```

where `foo` is the name of the remote branch.

Comment: If you already created your git branch, you can also use `git rebase` to rebase it onto the svn branch.

Comment: http://www.jukie.net/~bart/blog/svn-branches-in-git returns error 500.   Has the blog moved or something?

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be the only way to get git to checkout a branch in non-detached state.

Comment: The Bart blog is archived on archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20130119234635/http://www.jukie.net/~bart/blog/svn-branches-in-git

Comment: Even the archive for Bart's Blog is broken now.

Comment: @rampion But how do you create the empty svn branch in the first place?

Comment: @Tom OP's question assumed an existing svn branch. If you want to create an empty svn branch, use [`git svn branch $BRANCHNAME`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266395/git-svn-how-do-i-create-a-new-svn-branch-via-git).  Note that not all your local git branches need to have a corresponding remote svn branch, just the ones you want to share.

Answer (score 30):

You might also have a look at this: [git-svn is a gateway drug - robby on rails](http://www.robbyonrails.com/articles/2008/04/10/git-svn-is-a-gateway-drug).

I used something like this when I needed to make sure that my local branch was pointing to the correct remote svn branch:

```
git branch -r
```

to get the name of the remote branch I want to be tracking. Then

```
git reset --hard remotes/svn-branch-name
```

to explicitly change my local branch to point to a different remote branch.

Comment: this is a manual process for forcing a local branch to update to the current state of a remote svn branch. the question as I read it has more to do with the remote tracking features of git and configuring git to automatically remote-track a specific branch in SVN.

Answer (score 10):

I needed to run 'git svn fetch' first, since the branch I wanted to associate with had been created after my git client.

Comment: thanks, for this tip, and as a note, if found you can see the remotes in .git/svn/refs/remotes, and if there's a new one, after you run 'git svn fetch', it should show up there.

Comment: careful about looking in .git, stuff in there can change. In particular, refs can be packed in packed-refs sometimes, particularly if they don't change much, and won't show up loose, even if they are present. git show-ref does this better, and (perhaps) git branch -r even better

Comment: if you run `get checkout -b git-topic-branch-name remote-branch-name` and get `fatal: git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches.`
Then run `git branch -r`, and if you don't see the branch, that's when `git svn fetch` is needed.  (`git svn rebase` won't pull the new branch, but `git svn fetch` will)

Answer (score 1):

I use git-svn but I haven't used the features that interoperate with SVN branches. Having said that, I notice that the tutorial you were following didn't use the [-T, -b, -t](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) options to git svn init. These options tell git-svn what the upstream trunk/branches/tags directories are named, which might be important in your situation.

Comment: Thanks, Greg. Unfortunately for me, that's the difference between my setup and the one in the blog.