# git-svn create branch off past revision

Tags: svn, git

I know how to [create an svn branch w/git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266395/git-svn-how-do-i-create-a-new-svn-branch-via-git). But, can I do that off of a past revision/commit ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answer for myself (and anyone else) - not strictly git-svn, but it works:

```
svn copy https://foo.com/svn/bar/trunk/@6635 https://foo.com/svn/bar/branches/mybranch -m 'creating a branch'
# in your git working directory
git svn fetch
git branch -a
```

You should see `remotes/mybranch` in that list, now create a local branch that tracks that remote

```
git checkout -b local_mybranch remotes/mybranch
```

Answer (score 5):

You just need to switch to (checkout) that revision first. Here's an example using git-svn only:

```
git checkout <sha1-of-past-commit>
git svn branch -m "Create branch for v1.2.3 hotfixes" hotfix-1.2.3
git checkout -b hotfix-1.2.3 remotes/hotfix-1.2.3
```

Tested on Git for Windows 1.9.0.msysgit.0.

Comment: Just used this method and it worked no problem. Just be aware that if you originally cloned the repo with a --prefix=<prefix> option, the remote branch name will be remotes/<prefix>/hotfix-1.2.3