# How do I add branches to .git/config?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

NOTE: This question is inspired by the [git-svn branching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974016/git-svn-branching) question and *NOT* a duplicate!

Without doing anything extraordinary when I checked out our svn-repo I got the following *.git/config* file:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    autocrlf = false
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = svn+ssh://my_server/opt/subversion/main/trunk
    fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn
[color]
    ui = true
```

When I try to use *git svn branch* I get the message:

```
Unknown branch destination
```

The reason for this is that branches is missing in *.git/config*. I whant the branches to go into a directory parallel to trunk. So for example a branch named *foo* should be found at this path:

```
svn+ssh://my_server/opt/subversion/main/branches/foo
```

If I am working in a separate branch made inside of git with *git checkout -b foo*, I then want to create the branch in subversion with:

```
git svn branch foo
```

How do I update *.git/config* to get this working? I would be expecting a message like the following from *git svn branch foo*:

```
Copying svn+ssh://my_server/opt/subversion/main/trunk at r8507 to svn+ssh://my_server/opt/subversion/main/branches/foo...
```

**Edit:**
What if I update the `svn-remote` section to:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = svn+ssh://my_server/opt/subversion/main
    fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/git-svn
    branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/branches/*
```

It looks like its the right thing to do and seems to be working when I have tried to do *git svn rebase* and *git svn branch*. Is this a working solution or will I mighty pile of mess if I work with this new *config* a while?

Comment: I think you have to create the initial git-svn clone by using the `-s` switch.

Comment: I have no specific memory of exactly of how the clone was done way back in time. But the repository is huge and I would really like to avoid having to do a new clone just to get the .git/config "correct"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem, because your `svn-remote.svn.url` is not the root of the repository and to fetch multiple branches it has to be. You can just change it and run fetch, but I am not sure git-svn can use the data it already has in such case. It won't be worse than re-cloning in any case.

Your config has to look like. When cloning, you get that by using the `-t trunk` option.

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = svn+ssh://my_server/opt/subversion/main
    fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
```

By default, trunk will go directly to remotes, but you can insert some name between, which is cleaner if you also have other remotes. I usually have `refs/remotes/svn/trunk`.

If you provided the `-b` option, you will also have

```
    branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/branches/*
```

but if you didn't, you can add it manually anytime. That's what you need to have to be able to import branches and to create branches.

Last the `-T` option would add

```
    tags = tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
```

which you can again add anytime later. Note though, that svn tags won't behave as git tags, they will still behave as branches.

For convenience the `-s` option to clone is shorthand for `-t trunk -b branches -T tags`.