# Create a svn branch from git when directory structure differs

Tags: git-svn

I created a local git copy of an svn repo with the following commands:

```
$ git svn init svn://host/path/to/repo/PROJECT/trunk workingcopy
$ cd workingcopy
$ git svn fetch
```

Now I'm trying to create an svn branch without success:

```
$ git svn branch -n mybranch -m "Branch for my things"
Multiple branch paths defined for Subversion repository.
You must specify where you want to create the branch with the --destination argument
```

In `.git/config` I do not have any entries under `[svn-remote "svn"]` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2980284/276457). I tried adding `branches = branches/*:refs/*` but this tries to create the branch under the trunk:

```
Copying svn://host/path/to/repo/PROJECT/trunk at r6684 to svn://host/path/to/repo/PROJECT/trunk/branches/mybranch
```

What do I need to do to create a branch in the correct location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I changed `.git/config` from:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = svn://host/path/to/repo/PROJECT/trunk
    fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/git-svn
```

to:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = svn://host/path/to/repo/PROJECT
    fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/git-svn
    branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/*
```

This worked, but I ran into problems trying to access the branch from a git repo on another machine. In the end, I pushed my changes to svn, then deleted my local git repo and cloned it properly this time:

```
$ git svn clone --standard-layout --prefix=svn/ svn://host/path/to/repo/PROJECT
```