# How to switch svn branches using git-svn?

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

#### Duplicate

> [How do I make git-svn use a particular svn branch as the remote repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192736/how-do-i-make-git-svn-use-a-particular-svn-branch-as-the-remote-repository)

I am using git-svn to track development by someone else on svn. I'm trying to figure out how to use gti-svn to switch from one svn branch to another. All the examples I have able to find talk about using svn switch as method to switch location instead of actual branches.

Essentially, I would like to start pulling from /svn/branch/1.3 instead of /svn/branch/1.2
using svn fetch.

Comment: Turns out this is a duplicate. Sorry.

Comment: I did not see a dup. Where did you see this?

Comment: I edited your question to provide a link.

Answer (score 21):

These commands have been incredibly useful for me when working on svn branches via git-svn:

```
#create local Git branch that mirrors remote svn branch

git checkout -b local/RELEASE-0.12 RELEASE-0.12 
#will connect with a remote svn branch named ‘RELEASE-0.12′

# -n will show which svn branch you will commit into:
git svn dcommit --dry-run
```

See full explanation in my article on [justaddwater.dk](http://www.justaddwater.dk/2009/03/09/using-git-for-svn-repositories-workflow/).

Comment: I was able to do this but my syntax was different `git checkout -b branchname origin/branchname`

Answer (score 8):

If you've cloned the SVN repository properly (using `-T -b -t` or `-s`), you should be able to use the git branch commands like:

```
git reset --hard remotes/branch

git checkout branch
```

etc.

Comment: What if I already have changes in my local repo that I push to a separate git repo on github? I created the repo originally using git svn clone http://svn/branch/1.2

Comment: git checkout branch doesn't destroy your changes. git reset --hard does.

Comment: If you use reset --hard here, you'll blow away any changes made locally on top of remotes/branch.

Comment: I do not own the svn repo and apparently only the branches are exposed (as releases). So this is not really a duplicate of the other request. In this scenario, I am not able to do a git branch -r followed by git checkout -b

Comment: Basically, git branch -r does not show the 1.3 branch just stuff under the 1.2.

Comment: How is the SVN repo structured?

Comment: Now that's a weird one. A repo like this normally calls for git svn clone http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source -b branches, but http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source returns HTTP 403, so that probably won't work.

Comment: That's my point, they have a strange setup and I've been trying to figure how to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, it works fine doing just

```
git checkout -b RELEASE-0.12 RELEASE-0.12
```

The `local/` prefix is not needed, and it is less confusing to me to leave it out. The old `RELEASE-0.12` branch is already a remote branch, so git will not confuse it with the new branch.

The command above will not create a tracking branch relationship. But that is not needed, `git svn rebase` works as expected anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the answers here and in the linked duplicate assume that the initial `git svn init`/`git svn clone` used the `-T -b -t` or `-s` parameters to link to an svn project structure. In those cases, a `git checkout -b` is sufficient to switch between the branches that the initial `init`/`clone` linked up between your git and svn repositories. `git branch -r` will even show you the svn linked branches that you can switch to.

If the initial `init`/`clone` was directly to a specific SVN branch, though (as the OP question suggests), then I think the *.git/config* file needs to be updated directly:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = https://svn/branch/1.3
    rewriteRoot = https://svn/branch/1.2
    fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn
```