# Git SVN rebase to tags only

Tags: svn, git, version-control, tags, git-svn

I'm extending an open source project with additional functionality. So I'll be basing my code on the released version of the source code. The open source project uses SVN and I uses Git.

How would I rebase only to the released version (SVN tags) instead of to the HEAD of trunk when a new version is released?

Thanks.

Comment: This question is not appropriate for the StackOverflow site.  Please visit SuperUser.com.

Comment: I would argue that this is an appropriate question for SO.  In fact, it's already been asked twice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728931/how-to-switch-svn-branches-using-git-svn , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192736/how-do-i-make-git-svn-use-a-particular-svn-branch-as-the-remote-repository

Answer (score 1):

You can do your work on a branch based off of a tag, which you can pull into your git repo with the `--tags=` option to `git svn init`.