# git svn workflow: how to use svn remote branches?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have cloned my svn repo using git, specifying branches and trunk (no tags involved). Then, I ran fetch for a limited range of revisions. Now, I have:

```
$ git branch
* master
```

and

```
$ git branch -r
  version-2.3.1
  version-2.3.2
  version-2.3.3
  trunk
```

So, I understand that these branches are remote branches, and I did read http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches , but because remote branches are new to me, I'm having a hard time understanding how to use that knowledge in a svn context. One person at this link [How to switch svn branches using git-svn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728931/how-to-switch-svn-branches-using-git-svn) said to just do:

```
git reset --hard remotes/branch
git checkout branch
etc
```

but the 2nd command, "git checkout branch" doesn't apply to me since I don't have any local branches.....

So, now that I've got a bunch of remote branches that correspond to svn branches, what is the recommended workflow for "svn switch"ing to one of the branches, dcommit'ing, then "svn switch"ing back to a different branch? I never use trunk, I'm always working on branches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you are in master branch, you just:

```
git reset --hard version-2.3.3
```

and then your master branch is same as remote branch version-2.3.3.

Create another branch:

```
git checkout -b local-version-2.3.1
git reset --hard version-2.3.1
```

Then you create a new branch named: local-version-2.3.1, and it's the same as remote branch version-2.3.1.

Good luck.

Comment: Do local branches get deleted when I "svn switch"?

Comment: Once I've created a local branch corresponding to each remote branch, I won't ever have to run the `git checkout -b local-version-X.Y.Z` command again?

Comment: If you commit all uncommit items, you will not get deleted local branches.

Comment: Actually you don't understand what's remote branches, the remote branches mean some branches you clone from remote, but now the remote branches are also locally. you got my point?

Comment: does `git svn fetch` only work on the current branch? Or does it update all of the remotes?

Comment: Oh, looks like fetch only works on the "remote we are tracking"

Comment: Yes... fetch only update the remotes...it does not work the current branch

Comment: I think in the git-svn manual, it when it says "remote we are tracking" under "fetch", it's talking about the svn remote specified in the .git/config file, so I guess it's fetching all branches.

Comment: Yes, you r right, for example, a remote is called 'Jinma', git fetch Jinma, it will fetch all branches of Jinma.